# Psycopg2 - Error during insert due to double quotes

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using Python + Psycopg2 to insert an array of texts.
`elems` column is of type `text[]`.

```
a = ["A ''B'' C"]

cursor.execute(f"""\
  INSERT INTO table(elems) \
  VALUES (ARRAY{a}::text[]) \
""")
```

Error:

```
column "A ''B'' C" does not exist
```

The error above is due to the double quotes from Python list.

Using a database tool, the exact query that works is:

```
INSERT INTO table(elems)
VALUES (ARRAY['A ''B'' C']::text[])
```

Now my question:
What's the proper way of inserting a Python list of strings where an element may contain a single quote?

Comment: 1) Reading the docs would be a good start [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and [List adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list). 2) This `["A ''B'' C", "D", "E"]` does not match `ARRAY['A ''B'' C']`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thank you. I have updated the input. I'm going to try out using `%s` as stated in the docs.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, oh I remember why I did not use `%s`. It is because if list is empty, it needs to specify the correct type like `ARRAY[]::text[]`. Does this typing happen automatically with `%s` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ["A ''B'' C"]

import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("insert into array_test(id, text_array) values(%s, %s)", [6, a])
con.commit()

select text_array from array_test where id = 6;
  text_array   
---------------
 {"A ''B'' C"}

cur.execute("insert into array_test(id, text_array) values(%s, %s)", [7, []])
con.commit()

select text_array from array_test where id = 7;
 text_array 
------------
 {}
```